# Web shader - three.js , need to fix?

Tags: three.js, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I used vUv = uv to deal with three.js material shader for IcosahedronGeometry. But is not working and I need some help to fix this shader:

```js
var container, 
    renderer, 
    scene, 
    camera, 
    mesh, 
    start = Date.now(),
    fov = 30;

window.addEventListener( 'load', function() {
container = document.getElementById( "container" );
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 
    fov, 
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 
    1, 
    10000 );
camera.position.z = 100;
camera.target = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
scene.add( camera );
material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent
} );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( 
    new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry( 20, 4 ), 
    material 
);
scene.add( mesh );
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
render();
} );

function render() {
renderer.render( scene, camera );
requestAnimationFrame( render );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r77/three.js"></script>
<head>
    <title>Shader test</title>
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">
vUv = uv;
varying vec3 N;
varying vec3 I;
varying vec4 Cs;
void main()
{
    vec4 P = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;    
    I  = P.xyz - vec3 (0);
    N  = gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal;
    Cs = gl_Color;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex; 
    //gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
} 
</script>
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="fragmentShader">
varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 N;
varying vec3 I;
varying vec4 Cs;
uniform float edgefalloff;
uniform float intensity;
uniform float ambient;
void main()
{
    float opac = dot(normalize(-N), normalize(-I));
    opac = abs(opac);
    opac = ambient + intensity*(1.0-pow(opac, edgefalloff));
    //opac = 1.0 - opac;  
    gl_FragColor =  opac * Cs;
    gl_FragColor.a = opac;
    //gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3( vUv, 0. ), 1. );
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You need just tu put all this code into one html5 and try to fix. I used comments because not let me add all html5 file.

Comment: Make sure to create an executable codesnippet on your own next time(the "<>" document button in the question editor), nobody here "needs" to do anything, also be more specific about your problem "not working"/"need to fix" is a pretty bad description. Consider taking a look at a basic glsl tutorial, imo the console output says it all: `ERROR: 0:43: 'vUv' : syntax error`

Comment: LJ - right , sorry I'm out of time , thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is need to add this:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha: true});
```

Some shader need to have this type of definition over webgl and three for material.

```
var customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
        p: { type: "f", value: 3 },
        glowColor: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(0x84ccff) },
    },
    vertexShader: $('#vertexShader').text,
    fragmentShader: $('#fragmentShader').text,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    transparent: true,
    depthWrite: false
});
```

You need to have one object to use the material shader. I don't tested with uv texture - just with this customMaterial.
Try to use it x-shader/x-vertex and the other x-shader/x-fragment even works with x-shader/x-vertex and x-shader/x-vertex.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">
varying vec3 vUv;
varying vec3 N;
varying vec3 I;
varying vec4 Cs;
void main()
{
    vUv = uv;
    vec4 P = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;    
    I  = P.xyz - vec3 (0);
    N  = gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal;
    Cs = gl_Color;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex; 
    //gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
} 
</script>
```

Notice where `vUv = uv` is set.

Also, you have both your shader tags with the `type="x-shader/x-vertex"`, the fragment shader should be `type="x-shader/x-fragment"`, (though it may not make a difference).

Also, you are using variables in your vertex shader starting with `gl_`. I'm not sure if these are available.
The available variables in the vertex shader in three.js (that I know of) are:
- uniform mat4 **modelMatrix** - object.matrixWorld
- uniform mat4 **modelViewMatrix** - camera.matrixWorldInverse * object.matrixWorld
- uniform mat4 **projectionMatrix** - camera.projectionMatrix
- uniform mat4 **viewMatrix** - camera.matrixWorldInverse
- uniform mat3 **normalMatrix** - inverse transpose of modelViewMatrix
- uniform vec3 **cameraPosition** - camera position in world space
- attribute vec3 **position** - vertex position
- attribute vec3 **normal** - vertex normal
- attribute vec2 **uv**
- attribute vec2 **uv2**

Comment: I think is come with three.js when take the object to apply the material with shader. I try to make one x-ray shader. My first example working well: vertexShader with:
        varying vec2 vUv;

        void main() {

            vUv = uv;
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

        }
and fragment shader with:

        varying vec2 vUv;

        void main() {

            // colour is RGBA: u, v, 0, 1
            gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3( vUv, 0. ), 1. );

        }

Comment: I have no idea what the above comment means. I also just noticed you both shader tags as `x-shader/x-vertex`, instead of one `x-shader/x-vertex` and the other `x-shader/x-fragment`